# How do I create a standalone app that saves inputs that can be recalled from memory after restarting the app?

Tags: android, python-standalone

Basically: I need a standalone application that keeps all input in memory (even after the program shuts down) and then upon typing "Recall whatever..." can recall whatever fact I replace the word whatever with i.e.

INPUT: Recall pi

OUTPUT: Pi is 3.14159

...but I want it to recall that fact because I inputted it and not because it is part of a imported math module.

I also want to be able to type 'Recall ALL DATA' and it prints a complete list of everything I have inputted so I can override facts by simply reprogramming the fact with different information i.e.

Select 1

INPUT: The colour of mice are green

RECALL: What colour are mice?

OUTPUT: The colour of mice are green

INPUT: The colour of mice are pink

RECALL: What colour are mice?

OUTPUT: The colour of mice are pink

(I already know this happens when you do the above - this is just an example of the program running)

I mainly want to give the application memory so that when you turn it off and then back on it can recall anything it has learned in the past.

The standalone application should be able to save all inputs into memory that remains even after the program is switched off.

For example, when started the application opens in its own window, then asks...

```
1. Input
2. Recall
```

and if selecting '1' I can enter any fact, using proper coding of course i.e.

```
bird = flying animal with feathers
pi = 3.14159
bedtime = 10.15pm
```

and stores the facts in it's standalone program until opened again and then I can enter '2' and ask it i.e.

```
"What is a bird?"
"What is pi?"
"What is my bedtime?"
```

and the program uses the inputs above to figure out what is being asked and answers the questions.

I have tried using

````
```
def submit():
    data={
        }
```
````

and

````
```
open with('')
```
````

codes but these don't apply to a standalone application.

*** As for operating systems, I do mean python on Windows but would also like an Android version if that is possible.

Comment: What language are you using?  You have 3 languages tagged-  CSS (which we know isn't right as it's a styling language for html), JS, and Python with a framework called standalone.  You wouldn't be using all 3.  Assuming you mean python and standalone, as that matches your function definition-  I don't think that supports Android.  I see Windows, Linux, and Mac support, not any mobile OS

Comment: *** As for operating systems, I do mean python on Windows but would also like an Android version if that is possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.